# Facebook Meta Tag PHP condition

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

I am having a problem trying to get this snippet of code to output a separate og:image meta tag for each image in the array.

```
 <?php    function catch_that_image() {
global $post, $posts;
$first_img = '';
ob_start();
ob_end_clean();
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
$first_img = $matches [1] [0];
if(empty($first_img)){
        //Defines a default image
        $first_img = "http://example.com/images/fbthumb.jpg";
    }
return $first_img;
}
 ?>
```

Currently the code is returning the first matched img src tag, but I would like it to return them all as separate tags so I can select which share image to use.

I know this line:

```
   $first_img = $matches [1] [0];
```

needs to be changed into some type of for each condition but Im not sure how.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is my code after the last suggestion:

```
<?php function catch_that_image() {
global $post, $posts;
$result = preg_match_all('#<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[^>]*>#i', $post->post_content, $matches);

return $matches[1];
```

}

?>

" />

I still cant figure it out.  Any ideas?

Comment: `<?php function catch_that_image() {
    global $post, $posts;
    $imgSources = array();
    $result = preg_match_all('#<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[^>]*>#i', $post->post_content, $matches);

    foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
        $imgSources[] = $match;
    }

    return $imgSources;
}


 ?>

<meta property="og:image" content="<?php if (function_exists('catch_that_image')) {echo catch_that_image(); }?>" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function. It will return an array of image sources. You could then always use the first image in the array as default image.

```
function catch_that_image() {
    global $post, $posts;
    $imgSources = array();
    $result = preg_match_all('#<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[^>]*>#i', $post->post_content, $matches);

    foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
        $imgSources[] = $match;
    }

    return $imgSources;
}
```

or simpler

```
function catch_that_image() {
    global $post, $posts;
    $result = preg_match_all('#<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[^>]*>#i', $post->post_content, $matches);

    return $matches[1];
}
```

Using the function:

```
$imageArray = catch_that_image();
foreach($imageArray as $image) {
    echo '<meta property=​"og:​image" content=​"$image">';
}
```

Comment: okay so I used the last one u gave me here and its still not returning the values.  I cant figure out how to add code to this so Ill add an edit to my original post.

Comment: In firebug its returning this:  <meta property=​"og:​image" content=​"Array">​